# Matplotlib similar axis scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I command matplotlib to plot my x- and y-axis to the same scale, i.e. that a unit length on both  axes correspond to to the same physical distance on my screen or ons a piece of paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_aspect()` method of `Axes`:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.gca().set_aspect("equal")
```